# How to fix my e^x approximation C program?

Tags: c, function, math, output

I have written a C program that should compute and print the approximation of e^x for all values up to n. I am using this equation to implement my program.

> f(x, n) = e^x = the sum of i=0 up to n= x^i/x! = x^0/0! + x^1/1! +
>   x^2/2! +....+ x^n/n!

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double factorial(int n){
        double fac =1;
        int i;
        for(i =1; i <= n; i++){ 
                fac *=n;
        }
        return fac;
}
double exponent(double x, int n){
        double sum, i;
        for(i = 0; i <=n; i++){
                sum +=  (pow(x, i)/ factorial(i));
        } 
        return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        int n = atoi(argv[1]);
        double x = atof(argv[2]);
        printf("\ti\tApproximantion\n");
        printf("-------------------------------------\n");
        int i;
        for(i =0; i <=n; i++){
               printf("\t%d\t%f\n", i, exponent(x,i));
        }
        printf("Exact Value =\t%12f\n", exp(x));
        return 0;
}//main
```

I am using iteration instead of recursion.
My current output using `./aprroximation 10 2.2` is:

```
        i       Approximation
-------------------------------------
        0       1.000000
        1       3.200000
        2       4.410000
        3       4.804370
        4       7.895877
        5       8.912368
        6       9.914798
        7       10.915101
        8       11.915134
        9       12.915137
        10      13.915137
Exact Value =       9.025013
```

the output should be: (ignore the space/tabbing)

```
   i Approximation
--------------------------------
   0   1.0000000000
   1   3.2000000000
   2   5.6200000000
   3   7.3946666667
   4   8.3707333333
   5   8.8002026667
   6   8.9576747556
   7   9.0071659835
   8   9.0207760712
   9   9.0241029815
   10   9.0248349018
Exact Value = 9.0250134994
```

I can't seem to find the problem in my code. I have looked at some pseudo-code for factorial and power functions and nothing stands out. My results continue to be wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: Recalculating the factorial over and over again is naive and expensive.

Comment: From your output it looks like the `sum` is incremented by 1 every time after step 9. Can you please check this, by inputing `n` not 10 but say 13-15 and see if that holds ?

Comment: And hmm I cannot reproduce with your code, the output differs: on [ideone](http://ideone.com/Bok1D8).

Comment: @duffymo of course it is expensive, but this looks rather like an exercise. Once it works, there is still time for optimization, but anyway, in the real world, we don't need that code because we would just use the `exp` function.

Comment: I think students should be taught to code and think properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see, you didn't initialize the variable `sum` inside the `exponent()` function. Initialize it to zero, otherwise the `exponent()` function looks ok.

```
double exponent(double x, int n){
    double sum = 0, i;
    for(i = 0; i <=n; i++){
        sum += pow(x, i)/ factorial(i);
    } 
    return sum;
}
```

---

**Update**

I spot another problem in the `factorial()` function. Just think, whether the statement inside the `for` loop is correct!

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++){ 
    fac *= n;
}
```

What you are computing here is not `n!`, it is `n^n`. You should do the following.

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++){ 
    fac *= i;
}
```

Comment: I did not notice that. This did help, but my highest number was still 4, so the output is wrong. Any other errors you can spot?

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems:

1. In the `exponent` function you don't initialize `sum`
2. Your `factorial` function is wrong.

If you had tested the `factorial` function separately you would have found out easily by yourself at least that problem.